Minimizing a pure quadratic function under box constraint
I currently have the following problem to solve :
$$
\underset{\mathbf{x}\geq \mathbf{1}}{\min} \quad \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{x}.
$$
Here $\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{1}$ refers to elementwise inequality, ie. $x_k \geq 1$ for all $k$.
I know my matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ is positive definite. I was thinking that this problem is easy when $\mathbf{Q}$ is diagonal, where the solution would then jut be $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{1}$.
However, what happens if $\mathbf{Q}$ is not diagonal ? Is it possible to diagonalize it and work in the new base ? So we have a matrix $\mathbf{P}$ that is orthonormal such that $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}^T$. Defining $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{x}$, the new problem then would become :
$$
\underset{\mathbf{P}\mathbf{y} \geq 1}{\min} \quad \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{y}.
$$
Now the objective is simpler, but my constraint is no longer as easy. Can I continue from here or is it a dead end ? I know I could just feed my problem into any solver but that is not what I want.
Thank you!

Does $x \ge 1$ mean $x_k \ge 1$ for all $k$?

Yes, I meant the elementwise inequality, I will edit the question

Here is a necessary and sufficient condition for $x^*=\vec{1}$ to be a solution (where $\vec{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the all-1 vector).
Problem: Suppose $Q$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix. We want to minimize $x^{\top}Qx$ subject to $x\geq \vec{1}$.
Claim: $x^*=\vec{1}$ is a solution if and only if $Q\vec{1}\geq \vec{0}$.
Proof (sufficiency): Suppose $Q\vec{1}\geq \vec{0}$. We want to show $\vec{1}$ is a solution. Clearly $\vec{1}$ satisfies the constraint (since $\vec{1}\geq \vec{1}$). Suppose $x$ is another vector that satisfies the constraint, so $x\geq \vec{1}$. We want to show $\vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1}\leq x^{\top}Q\vec{x}$. We have $x=\vec{1}+y$ for some $y\geq \vec{0}$. Then
\begin{align}
x^{\top}Qx&=(\vec{1}+y)^{\top}Q(\vec{1}+y) \\
&= \vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1} + 2y^{\top}Q\vec{1} + y^{\top}Qy\\
&\geq \vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1} + 2y^{\top}Q\vec{1}\\
&\geq \vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1}
\end{align}
where the first inequality holds because $y^{\top}Qy\geq 0$; the second holds because $y\geq \vec{0}$ and $Q\vec{1}\geq 0$ so their inner product is nonnegative. $\Box$
Proof (necessity): Suppose $\vec{1}$ is a solution. We want to show $Q\vec{1}\geq 0$. Define
$$r=Q\vec{1}$$
Then $r=(r_1, ..., r_n)$. Fix $j\in \{1, ..., n\}$. It suffices to show $r_j\geq 0$.  Fix $\epsilon>0$. Define $x=\vec{1} + \epsilon e_j$ where $e_j\in\{0,1\}^n$ is the vector that is 1 in entry $j$ and zero elsewhere. Observe that $x$ satisfies the constraint $x\geq \vec{1}$. Since $\vec{1}$ minimizes the objective over all vectors that satisfy the constraint, we have
\begin{align}
\vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1}&\leq x^{\top}Qx\\
&=(\vec{1}+\epsilon e_j)Q(\vec{1}+\epsilon e_j)\\
&=\vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1} + 2\epsilon e_j^{\top}Q\vec{1} + \epsilon^2 e_j^{\top}Qe_j\\
&=\vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1} + 2\epsilon e_j^{\top}r + \epsilon^2 e_j^{\top}Qe_j\\
&= \vec{1}^{\top}Q\vec{1} + 2\epsilon r_j + \epsilon^2e_j^{\top}Qe_j
\end{align}
and so for all $\epsilon>0$ we have
$$ 0\leq 2\epsilon r_j + \epsilon^2(e_j^{\top}Qe_j)$$
Dividing by the positive value $\epsilon>0$ gives
$$ 0 \leq 2r_j + \epsilon (e_j^{\top}Qe_j) \quad \forall \epsilon>0$$
Taking $\epsilon\searrow 0$ gives
$0 \leq 2r_j$, so $r_j\geq 0$. $\Box$

Example 1: Suppose $n=2$. As an example where $(1,1)$ is not optimal, consider the following symmetric and positive definite matrix:
$$Q=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 90 & -15 \\ -15 & 5\end{array}\right]$$
Then $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ both satisfy the constraint $x\geq \vec{1}$, but
$$ \left[1 \: 1\right]Q\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\end{array}\right] = 65$$
$$ \left[1 \: 2\right]Q\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\end{array}\right] = 50$$
So $(1,1)$ is not an optimal solution. Of course, this example fails the condition $Q\vec{1}\geq \vec{0}$.
Example 2: Fix $z\geq 5$ and define the positive definite matrix:
$$Q_z=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 90 & -15 \\ -15 & z\end{array}\right]$$
This meets the condition $Q_z\vec{1}\geq\vec{0}$ if and only if $z\geq 15$.   So $(1,1)$ is a solution if and only if $z\geq 15$.
